# MATLAB: Select all of an array EXCEPT in given ranges

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I'd like to perform metrics on the contents of an array that do NOT fall within certain ranges.

For example, I have an array with 1000 rows and 2 columns. I'd like to perform a mean() calculation on all the elements in one column (let's say column #2) that don't fall in rows 50-150, 250-300, 400-700 and 900-950.

Thus, the mean should be calculated based on rows 1-49, 151-249, 301-399, 701-899 and 951-1000.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Edit: I should point out that those items which are included will change each time the program is run. Therefore, I can't just hard-code the inclusions in; they need to be worked out based on the exclusions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
M = rand(1000,2);
idx = setdiff(1:size(M,1), [50:150, 250:300, 400:700, 900:950]);

MM = M(idx,:)
```

Now apply any function to the filtered matrix:

```
mean(MM,1)
```

Comment: I should point out that those inclusions are arbitrary; I need to be able to have the system work out what the 'idx' inclusions are based on knowing the ones which are excluded; i.e. I can't manually type in the inclusions since they will change depending on the input data.

Comment: @CaptainProg: I added a note about using SETDIFF

Answer (score 0):

You can define the exclusion ranges and then use logical addressing:

```
LowerLimit1 = 1;
UpperLimit1 = 50;

LowerLimit2 = 151;
UpperLimit2 = 249;

LowerLimit3 = 301;
UpperLimit3 = 399;

LowerLimit4 = 701;
UpperLimit4 = 899;

LowerLimit5 = 951;
UpperLimit5 = 1000;

MyVector = MyMatrix(:,2);

MeanValue = mean(MyVector(~(MyVector > LowerLimit1 & MyVector < UpperLimit1) | (MyVector > LowerLimit2 & MyVector < UpperLimit2) |  (MyVector > LowerLimit3 & MyVector < UpperLimit3)  | (MyVector > LowerLimit4 & MyVector < UpperLimit4) | (MyVector > LowerLimit5 & MyVector < UpperLimit5)));
```

Comment: a possible generalization of this: `r = [50 150; 250 300; 400 700; 900 950]; idx = find(all( ~(bsxfun(@ge, 1:size(M,1), r(:,1)) & bsxfun(@le, 1:size(M,1), r(:,2))) ));` where `r` contains the lower/upper limits of each exclude range