# All pixels except one pixel in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

Say that we have a `3x3` matrix in `matlab`. If we type `x(:)`, this will select **all** the elements in the matrix, right?

How can we select all the elecments **except** element `x(2,2)`? What should we type in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11054728/2065121

Comment: @EitanT: I just created a new tag [tag:matrix-indexing], which should apply to lots of questions.. I cant believe this hasn't been done before :) The existing tags refer to databases indexing

Comment: thanks, now lets hope others pick up on it.

Comment: @Amro I've done my share of tagging now (by the way, I've also noticed the misuse of the [tag:delete] tag, which really refers to deleting files, not elements from an array).

Comment: @EitanT: appreciate it, thanks. I wish stack exchange would introduce new 10K tools for mass retagging :)

Comment: @Amro Nice idea, you should post it on Meta. Some tool that accepts rules, for example: "_retag all [tag:index]-tagged questions that are also [tag:matlab] questions with [tag:matlab-indexing]_".

Comment: I wonder if moderators have access to such tools... Another area lacking is synonyms suggestion; speaking of which could you take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab-compiler/synonyms , its so hard to get attention to these suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this: first, create a logical array of `true`s, which would select **all** elements if used as an index mask:

```
mask = true(size(x) );
```

Now set element 2,2 to be false, therefore deselecting it:

```
mask(2,2) = false;
```

Now use this mask to select elements from `x`:

```
myValues = x(mask);
```

---

**EDIT:** Removed second, incorrect answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried your *simpler* solution, I got this error: `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.`. Why is that?

Comment: You can't remove an element that would result in a "non-rectangular matrix", so to speak. The method based on logical indexing is more expressive, anyways, and does not involve mutating a matrix.

Comment: @JoshuaBarr You're correct, apologies.  As I said I saw it on another answer, I hadn't followed it through properly.

Comment: @Med-SWEng My mistake (see Joshua's comment), go with the first solution in this case!

Comment: @jazzbassrob The second answer is also fine, with a minor adjustments. Convert the original matrix into a column vector first and then use or linear indices (or `sub2ind`) to remove elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 A(setdiff(1:numel(A),ceil(numel(A)/2)))
```

---

For example, for the input as:

```
>> A = randi(100,3)

A =

    49    71    68
    45    76    66
    65    28    17
```

The output is:

```
>> A(setdiff(1:numel(A),ceil(numel(A)/2)))

ans =

    49    45    65    71    28    68    66    17
```